# using fancybox tool for image gallery not working

Tags: html, css

im trying to add fancybox tool to my page, its working but not as this example:

my code:

```
<head>
<title>Image  Gallery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/CSS/style.css">
<link rel="styleshhet" href="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/CSS/jquery.fancybox.css">
<link rel="styleshhet" href="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/CSS/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css">
<link rel="styleshhet" href="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/CSS/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css">


<script src="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script src = "file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/js/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
<script src = "file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.javascript"></script>

<script type ="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".fancybox").fancybox();  


  });
</script>


</head>



<body>

  <header>
    <div class="container">
<img src="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/images/logo.jpg" class="logo">
</div>
  </header>

<div class="container">
  <section>
<div class="gallery">
<a class ="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/images/img1.jpg">
<img src="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/images/img1.jpg"></a>

<a class ="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/images/img2.jpg">
<img src="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/images/img2.jpg"></a>

<a class ="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/images/img3.jpg">
<img src="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/images/img3.jpg"></a>

<a class ="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/images/img4.jpg">
<img src="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/images/img4.jpg"></a>

<a class ="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/images/img5.jpg">
<img src="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/images/img5.jpg"></a>

<a class ="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/images/img6.jpg">
<img src="file:///D:/CSS%20projects/image%20gallery/images/img6.jpg"></a>
</div>



  </section>
  <aside>
  <nav>
<a data-rel="all"href="javascript;">view all</a>
<a data-rel="category1" href="javascript;">category 1</a>
<a data-rel="category2" href="javascript;">category 2</a>


  </nav>
</aside>
</div>

<footer>
<div class="container">
  <p>Copyright &copy; 2014</p> 
</div>
</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

i download all css,java files correct and linked them in my HTML file.

however, the result is that the picture just popup normal but it also jumping a bit like its stuck. its look like i just forget  line of something..

thanks.

Comment: sorory i forget to put the image like i want it to work(image gallery with buttons)                                                                                                       
http://postimg.org/image/e2c65kgdn/

Answer (score 0):

`$(".fancybox")` returns all the elements with the class fancybox. You need to iterate over each element using JQuery's [`$.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: i didn't understand where i need to use it/to put it. can you show me an example please?